# $\binom{p^{\alpha}-1}{k} = (-1)^k\pmod{p}$?

Tags: number-theory

I need to show that

$$\binom{p^{\alpha}-1}{k} = (-1)^k\pmod{p}$$

for $0 \leq k \leq p^{\alpha}-1$. Not really sure how to start going about this... how should I transform the term on the left? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$ \binom{p^\alpha-1}{k} = \frac{(p^{\alpha}-1)(p^{\alpha}-2)\cdots(p^{\alpha}-k)}{(1)(2)\cdots(k)}. $$
Now take everything modulo $p$.